# Create Multiple Images with php

Tags: php, image, joomla, thumbnails

I have that free php code-function (of Pedro Pinheiro https://github.com/pedroppinheiro)

```
function createThumbnail($filepath, $thumbpath, $thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height, $background=false) {
    list($original_width, $original_height, $original_type) = getimagesize($filepath);
    if ($original_width > $original_height) {
        $new_width = $thumbnail_width;
        $new_height = intval($original_height * $new_width / $original_width);
    } else {
        $new_height = $thumbnail_height;
        $new_width = intval($original_width * $new_height / $original_height);
    }
    $dest_x = intval(($thumbnail_width - $new_width) / 2);
    $dest_y = intval(($thumbnail_height - $new_height) / 2);

if ($original_type === 1) {
    $imgt = "ImageGIF";
    $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromGIF";
} else if ($original_type === 2) {
    $imgt = "ImageJPEG";
    $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromJPEG";
} else if ($original_type === 3) {
    $imgt = "ImagePNG";
    $imgcreatefrom = "ImageCreateFromPNG";
} else {
    return false;
}

$old_image = $imgcreatefrom($filepath);
$new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($thumbnail_width, $thumbnail_height); // creates new image, but with a black background

// figuring out the color for the background
if(is_array($background) && count($background) === 3) {
  list($red, $green, $blue) = $background;
  $color = imagecolorallocate($new_image, $red, $green, $blue);
  imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $color);
// apply transparent background only if is a png image
} else if($background === 'transparent' && $original_type === 3) {
  imagesavealpha($new_image, TRUE);
  $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($new_image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
  imagefill($new_image, 0, 0, $color);
}

imagecopyresampled($new_image, $old_image, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $original_width, $original_height);
$imgt($new_image, $thumbpath);
return file_exists($thumbpath);
```

}`

it creates thumbnails from single image file when you call function like this

```
$success = createThumbnail(__DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'image.jpg', __DIR__.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'image_thumb.jpg', 60, 60, array(255,255,255));
```

It is okay for single image file but I want it to convert all images in a folder what should I do? When I use for each it does not work.
I am trying to develop a joomla module I have that code that grabbing images

```
static function getList($params) {
    $filter = '\.png$|\.gif$|\.jpg$|\.bmp$';
    $path       = $params->get('path');
    $files      = JFolder::files(JPATH_BASE.$path,$filter);

    $i=0;
    $lists = array();

    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $lists[$i]['title'] = JFile::stripExt($file);
        $lists[$i]['image'] = JURI::base().str_replace(DS,'/',substr($path,1)).'/'.$file;
        $i++;
    }
    return $lists; 
}
```

Then I add this to create thumbnails

```
    <?php 
$filepath=JUri::root()  . '/images/';
$thumbpath=JUri::root()  . '/images/thumbs/';
$success=createThumbnail($filepath, $thumbpath, 160, 160, array(0,0,0));
?>
<?php  foreach ($lists as $item):?>

   <div>
   <?php echo $success;?>
   </div>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

But it fails. thanks in advance.

Comment: explain "it does not work" with more explicit words and post your foreach code.

Comment: Thanks for answer I have edited my first message and gave more details please check.

Comment: Since `file_exists()` return a boolean (true or false), you're not likely to actually see anything printed as a result of your `createThumbnail()` method. Just debug step by step adding `print_r()` calls just about everywhere to see what's going on precisely.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I am actually looking thumbs folder if ther is any thumbs created and check it.But I will take your advice ans see step by step what is going on.